# Peaceful "docker stop" when running exec in background w/ docker container via shell script

Tags: bash, docker, nginx

I have a Docker container running a UWSGI server that's serving an API built in Python using Flask, which has the command `ENTRYPOINT ["./startapi.sh"]` to start up the server when the container is built. The container uses nginx as a reverse proxy to handle requests and serve them to the API inside the UWSGI instance.

`startapi.sh` contains the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
service nginx start
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini &
while :; do nginx -s reload; sleep 6h; done
```

However, when I try to `docker stop` the container, it waits the full 10s before sending SIGKILL to the container because PID 1 inside the container is `/bin/bash ./startapi.sh`. I know why--because the SIGTERM that `docker stop` sends doesn't reach the UWSGI instance, as it is not PID 1.

I know how to resolve that--just remove the `&` from the end of `exec uwsgi` in `startapi.sh`--but then the while loop won't run because it follows the `exec uwsgi` command (at least, I don't see the loop when I run `docker exec -it container.name ps auxww` from the host). Swapping the two lines (putting the `while` loop before the `exec uwsgi`) will properly run the sleep command to reload nginx, but will fail to run `exec uwsgi` and therefore not launch the API.

My dilemma, thus, is this--I want PID 1 in my container to be `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` so that `docker stop` gracefully stops the UWSGI server (and yes, I do have `hook-master-start = unix_signal:15 gracefully_kill_them_all` in my `uwsgi.ini` per a [UWSGI GitHub](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/849#issuecomment-118869386) issue, so it should comply with `docker stop` SIGTERM), but I also want to be able to reload nginx automatically every 6hrs via the while loop/`sleep` one-liner.

Is there something I can do to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you running both of these services in a single container? I would split this into two containers: one running the uwsgi app, and the other running nginx.

Comment: Unrelated, but note that `service nginx start` does absolutely nothing in the context of a typical container (because there is no service manager with which it can communicate).

Comment: To add to the above comments, you should investigate docker-compose to run these containers side-by-side, which takes care of all the process management you are attempting manually.  See [this repo](https://github.com/testdrivenio/flask-on-docker) and the included tutorial.

Comment: `will properly run the sleep command to reload nginx, but will fail to run exec uwsgi` why does it fail?!

Comment: @v25 thanks for the link, will look into it more. i'm somewhat new to docker and even more new to building web APIs, so i'll look into it and see if i can make my project's structure a little closer to theirs.

Comment: @larsks re: the `service` line, does the fact that the container comes with nginx (i'm using tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8 instead of something like, idk, python-slim or someth) make that line redundant then?

as for why i'm running them in the same container: i (naively) believed it would be simpler to do it this way i guess. clearly that's not best practice though from what i can tell

Comment: @KamilCuk from what `ps auxww` shows, the container doesn't get to `exec` because the `while` loop is always set to True (which is intended) and breaking the loop to start the uwsgi instance defeats the whole purpose of having the while loop in the first place. more specifically, i see nginx worker/master processes and a `sleep 6h` process, but no uwsgi processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So swap them. Literally. Run the loop in the background.

```
#!/bin/bash
service nginx start
while :; do nginx -s reload; sleep 6h; done &
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

But really, you should be running `supervisord` instead.

Also, consider `inotifywait` and executing `nginx -s reload` when the config changed.

Comment: not sure why you're -1, and for my purposes this does pretty much what i needed. so thanks! feel a bit dumb for not trying this earlier.